# Как занести в базу вывод от результата select

Tags: python, mysql

Помогите написать код,что бы вывод от этого скрипта, заносился в другую в базу.

```
db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="password")
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * from........."
cursor.execute(sql)
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

Вид каждой записи такой:

```
print(result)

(datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 22, 10, 45, 41), datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 22, 10, 47, 40), 'g2', 'inz', 1, 'active', 'mail', 'k08', 'ha', 'e1c96247bbfeaedd144')
```

Comment: Другую базу - на том же инстансе MySQL? PS. У Вас вообще отсутствует код изменения текущей БД.

Comment: @Akina на том же инстансе

Comment: Ну тогда простой `INSERT .. SELECT`, с указанием БД у таблиц. `INSERT INTO db2.table2 (columns) SELECT columns FROM db1.table1 WHERE conditions`.

Comment: @Akina я не совсем понимаю как переменные из первого запроса отправить в value второго. for r in results:
    sql_insert = "INSERT INTO `table2` (`id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `username`, `project`, `vm_state`, `power_state`, `email`, `status_send`, `emaildate`, `host`, `vmname`, `uuid`, `statusremove`) VALUES (NULL, '+r[1]+' , '+r[2]+', 'a', 'project_name', '2', 'Active', 'aap@mail.ru', '0', NULL, 'bi1', 'vm-name', 's2a213123132', '0');"
 в r[1].r[2] данные из селекта первой таблице, вот я пытаюсь в value подставить, а мне текстом туда пишет, а не значения.

Comment: *как переменные из первого запроса отправить в value второго* Да вообще никак. Нафига это надо? *я пытаюсь в value подставить* Когда найдёте слово VALUES в моих предыдущих комментариях, вот тогда сразу поймёте. PS. [INSERT ... SELECT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: @Akina у меня во второй таблице, другие поля, и этих полей больше. Поэтому мне не 1 в 1 надо, а в определенные поля занести значения переменных из 1ой таблице.

Comment: И чё? Большая проблема написать правильный SELECT, который вернёт ровно то, что надо класть во вторую таблицу?

Comment: @Akina ок, мысль понятна, но все же, как передать мне значения r[1] в запрос insert в values? VALUES (NULL, '+r[1]+' )

Comment: Последний раз повторяю. В запросе в принципе не должно быть слова VALUES.

Comment: @user405396 есть два способа вставить данные. 1. Вычитать в питон, обработать и потом вставить. 2. Сделать один SQL запрос, который сделает выборку и одновременно вставит данные. Что в одном, что в другом случае можно данные перед вставкой преобразовать в нужный формат, вопрос только в удобстве. Второй способ не годится, если перед вставкой нужно, например, сделать запрос к внешнему сервису. Akina пишет вам о втором способе, а вам похоже нужен первый. Тогда и вопрос задайте более конкретный (если еще такой не задан), а именно "как вставить запись в mysql из python"- именно в этом загвоздка.